# Autolayout constraint throws exception in production

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am running into a very strange issues that I can't seem to figure out how to get working.  When I debug my application on my device or on a simulator I don't get any errors.  When I build it for ad-hoc deployment, the app throws an exception and fails.  The error I'm getting in the log is

```
[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
```

My layout looks like this across the board for all of my views.

[image]

My constraints stretch views out to the full width of the screen, and I'm creating a dynamic width constraint on the views in my BaseViewController that gets inherited by all the other ones.  I've created my delegates for the scrollView and contentView for each of my subviews.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
var activeField:UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if(self.scrollView != nil)
    {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let leftConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        self.view.addConstraint(leftConstraint)

        let rightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        self.view.addConstraint(rightConstraint)
    }

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

I'm more than happy to provide any additional information, please just ask and I'll give you what I can.

**EDIT**

This only happens on archiving and running without connected to a debugger.  If I debug a release build no issue.

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
var activeField:UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true);
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(field: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    field.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(sender: UITextField)
{
    self.activeField = sender
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(sender: UITextField)
{
    self.activeField = nil
}

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if(self.activeField != nil && self.scrollView != nil) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)

            self.scrollView!.contentInset = contentInsets
            self.scrollView!.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

            var aRect = self.view.frame
            aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.size.height

            if(!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeField!.frame.origin)) {
                self.scrollView!.scrollRectToVisible(self.activeField!.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }            
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if(self.scrollView != nil) {
        let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

        self.scrollView!.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView!.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }
}
}
```

My logs look like this now and I'm not sure what my issue is.

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed: 
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193c19690 __sfvwrite + 0
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193c20958 __vfprintf + 11352
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193c3b67c __v2printf + 584
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193bce208 _vsnprintf + 300
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193bcec54 snprintf_l + 20
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181cc7018 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 11580
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181cc42a0 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 244
7   Foundation                      0x0000000182b0a444 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 168
8   Foundation                      0x0000000182b0a304 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 72
9   yazda-ios                       0x00000001000fcea0 +[NRMAThreadLocalStore currentThreadDictionary] (NRMAThreadLocalStore.m:238)
10  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000fb678 +[NRMAThreadLocalStore threadLocalTrace] (NRMAThreadLocalStore.m:36)
11  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000fc040 +[NRMAThreadLocalStore prepareSameThread:child:withParent:] (NRMAThreadLocalStore.m:126)
12  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000fbac0 +[NRMAThreadLocalStore pushChild:forParent:] (NRMAThreadLocalStore.m:91)
13  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000c92d4 +[NRMATraceController newTraceSetup:parentTrace:] (NRMATraceController.m:310)
14  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000c97d8 +[NRMATraceController enterMethod:fromObject:parentTrace:traceCategory:withTimer:] (NRMATraceController.m:374)
15  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000c95ac +[NRMATraceController enterMethod:fromObject:parentTrace:traceCategory:] (NRMATraceController.m:338)
16  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000b4498 NRMA__beginMethod (NRMAMethodProfiler.m:1051)
17  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000b406c NRMA__voidParamHandler (NRMAMethodProfiler.m:705)
18  yazda-ios                       0x0000000100047f38 yazda_ios.BaseViewController.viewDidLoad (yazda_ios.BaseViewController)() -> () (BaseViewController.swift:32)
19  yazda-ios                       0x00000001000b407c NRMA__voidParamHandler (NRMAMethodProfiler.m:707)
20  yazda-ios                       0x0000000100047f38 yazda_ios.BaseViewController.viewDidLoad (yazda_ios.BaseViewController)() -> () (BaseViewController.swift:32)
```

Comment: for the views that you are adding constraints to programatically, have you set translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints to NO?

Comment: I am not currently.  Would I need to set that on the parent view, the scroll view or my content view?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue.  For some reason I had a dependency issue or build issue with you my ViewController inherited my BaseViewController.

For some reason one of the methods wasn't returning like it was supposed to and it blew everything up.

Answer (score 0):

Two constraints are in contradiction with each others so you might be facing so